# Can't select the first value in the list in angular 9 app?

Tags: angular

I have the following enum and object in angular 9 app:

```
export enum Frequency {
    Q='Quarterly',
    M='Monthly'
}

export class FrequencyUI {
  public frequency: Frequency;
  public name: string;

  constructor(frequency: Frequency, name: string) {
    this.frequency = frequency;
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Here is entity:

```
export class Fund {
public subscription_frequency?: Frequency;
}
```

I'm using the enum values in a select as following:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="fund.subscription_frequency" #subscriptionFrequency="ngModel" name="subscription_frequency" [compareWith]="compareSubscriptionFrequenciesByOptionId" required>                                       
        <option [ngValue]="null">{{defaultSelect}}</option>
        <option *ngFor="let sf of frequencies" [ngValue]="sf.frequency">{{sf.name}}</option>
</select>
```

This is the compare method, I believe the problem is here cause null value is compared with other, the question is what I need to change in this method
to get things working.

```
compareSubscriptionFrequenciesByOptionId(idFirst, idSecond) {      
    return idFirst && idSecond && idFirst.frequency == idSecond.frequency;         
  }
```

The problem is that when I select the first value it is saved in the database (spring boot) but
ONLY when I select the first value in the list when I come back to the page the value is not selected.
Please let me know if you wanna see something from the server.
Thanks!

Comment: Please add a reproducible example. The code you pasted clearly is not complete. You populate `ngModel` from `fund.subscription_frequency`, and `fund` is nowhere to be seen in the component.

Comment: I'll add the entity where the frequency is there, no probs

Answer (score 0):

Most common mistake: When your data comes back from the server you should cast your enum value explicitly in Javascript code:

```
fundDto.subscription_frequency = Frequency[fundDto.subscription_frequency]
```

I typically do it in observable pipe:

```
<observable_here>.pipe(
  tap(fundDto.subscription_frequency = Frequency[fundDto.subscription_frequency])
);
```

Comment: The type was in the question cause I deleted the css class can you remove the answer, thanks

Comment: ok. removed. have you tried the enum cast?

Comment: I just  did your first code and now I can't select any value, I remind you that everything is working fine, just the first value!

Answer (score 0):

Make FrequencyUI frequency property optional:
frequency?: Frequency

Or add the Frequency enum option 'none':

```
enum Frequency{
  None = 'none'
  ...
}
```

Keep in mind: The issue can be in the compareWith

Comment: The issue must be with the compareWith for sure, I'll this code to the question and maybe you can contribute with an answer, adding None won't work cause I'm not willing to save None